# Boundedness of dimension of representations that restrict to a fixed representation of a normal subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, induced-representations

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group, $H$ a closed subgroup and $W$ an irreducible real representation of $G$. Then it follows from Frobenius reciprocity and Bott’s definition of induced representation that  there is an irreducible  representation $V$ of $G$ such that the restriction of $V$ to $H$ contains $W$ as a direct summand. My question is: if $H$ is normal in $G$ is there a constant $c$ that depends only on $G$ and $H$ such that for any representation W of H there is always a representation $V$ of $G$ with $\dim V \leq c\dim W$?  The answer is no if there is a group $G$ with  the dimension of the center of $G$ ${}> 0$ and $\lim\dim(V_n) = \infty$ where the $V_n$ are the irreducible representations of $G$.

Comment: Just to be clear, you aren't (as your title seems to suggest) asking for a bound on the dimension of *every* such $V$, just a bound on the dimension of *some* such $V$?

Comment: Correct. The question is: does there exist an irreducible V such that..

Comment: Should that first sentence read "$W$ an irreducible representation of $H$"?

Comment: So, what you have asked for is false for $G=U(n)$ and H=centre of $U(n)$?

Comment: I should have said that c can also depend on dim W.  As for U(n) I believe the irreducibles do not satisfy lim dim V_n = ∞. There are an infinite number of irreducibles of dimension 1 given by powers of the determinant representation.

Comment: Ouch! Qiaochu Yuan is correct; W is an irreducible representation of H not G.